# XNA. Texture2D. SetData. Wrong Alpha Channel

Tags: c#, colors, xna, texture2d

This code creates a texture with a nonzero alpha channel.

```
Texture2D result = new Texture2D(Program.MainThread.GraphicsDevice, (Int32)texture_size, (Int32)texture_size);
Color[ ] colorData = new Color[result.Width * result.Height];
for (UInt32 x = 0; x < result.Width; x++) {
    for (UInt32 y = 0; y < result.Height; y++) {
        UInt32 index = (UInt32)(x * result.Width + y);
        colorData[index] = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    }
}
result.SetData(colorData);
```

The color becomes slightly transparent. But, approximately, to the value of 0.5f. Why is this happening?

P.S. Color.Transparent works correctly, but I have an alpha channel to be calculated programmatically, for example:

```
colorData[index] = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f - temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make textures transparent in XNA, I find that doing the following works much better:

```
Color color = new Color(r,g,b) * alpha;
```

See if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because XNA 4.0+ uses [premultiplied alpha](http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blog/premultiplied-alpha.html). It's just a differnet concept of dealing with transparency. For example, to properly get a color completely transparent, you have to set red, green and blue to 0 while setting alpha to 255.